# I made a huge technical mistake in an arXiv paper... How bad is it?

Tags: arxiv, errors-erratum, retraction

I made a huge technical mistake in a paper I published on arXiv... How bad is it in academia?

Comment: Does *huge* refer to the impact of the mistake or is it particularly shameful as you should have noticed or known better?

Comment: I think nobody can give exact answer to "how bad it is?" questions unless he exactly knows "how huge it is".

Comment: Check the advice in the answers, take the required actions and don't worry, how many people are going to actually [read](http://chris2x.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/dispair-blog.jpg) the paper?

Comment: In the best case, even if you don't know how to fix it, someone else might. This could result in a joint paper. This might sound overly optimistic, but it has happened, for instance, with this paper: [arXiv:1003.3713](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.3713).

Comment: You can submit a revision.

Answer (score 42):

Mistakes are "bad" in academia if you fail to disclose them once you know about them (which constitutes unethical behavior), or if they affect something that counts towards a formal credential (like a degree; which is unlikely for an arXiv submission).

So, the way forward is:

- Inform your co-authors (if there were any).
- Upload an updated version of your paper to arXiv, in which you place a big notice at the top stating that there is a major technical error and the contents of the paper should not be considered accurate.
- Then [withdraw](http://arxiv.org/help/withdraw) the submission from arXiv with an appropriate notice as to the nature of the error.

Then, if you think you can correct the error and rescue the rest of the paper, get to work on that.

Academics make mistakes all the time. Acknowledge your error, disclose it, and move on.

Comment: If the mistake seems fixable in a reasonable amount of time, or if some parts of the paper are salvageable, it may be both ethically correct and less career-damaging to simply modify the paper and upload a new version (making clear in the comments that a mistake was handled).

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner sure, but given the characterization as a "huge technical error," I think it's unlikely; in any case, I don't think withdrawing an arxiv submission is "career-damaging"

Comment: The nature of the mistake is a bit difficult to assess, and the comment was also meant as more general cases; also withdrawing an arXiv submission is probably not very harmful if one already has a good and long publication record, but it does look quite bad if you have say two papers, one withdrawn (but if it is what needs to be done given the error, it could of course be even more harmful not to withdraw it).

Comment: _but it does look quite bad if you have say two papers, one withdrawn_ — That doesn't look _bad_ so much as _young_.